# R what is wrong with my code to loop thru files in dir and do replace

Tags: r

I  try to reuse some old code one co-worker gave (and learn). Read all files in path with .sql extension and do some replace and then write them out under new name or save edited.
After that I still don't have full name in my  and for command can't find path, then after testing I point to some file directly and got some  error. I'm all on Windows machine.

```
path = "c:/WorkDir/Alpha/"
out.file<-""
file.names <- dir(path, pattern =".sql")
for(i in 1:length(file.names)){
  file <- read.table(file.names[i])
 gsub( "Merry Christmas", "Happy New Year", file )
  out.file <- rbind(out.file, file)
  write.table(out.file, file = c(file,"new")
}
```

so file.names shows like xxx.sql without  portion, is it  command should take care of??

Thanks much
M

Answer (score 1):

So there are some problems with your code.
First, `gsub` is a function that return the result of the replacement you have done. It doesn't make replacement inside the data you pass in the function. So you should save the result and use it later.

```
my_vec = c("Merry Christmas", "2015")
my_new_vec = gsub("Merry Christmas", "Happy New Year", my_vec)
print(my_vec)  #  [1] "Merry Christmas" "2015"
print(my_new_vec)  # [1] "Happy New Year" "2015"
```

Then, you should be sure that your working directory is set correctly. `write.table` will save your file ".sql" in your working directory for a relative link like yours.

```
getwd()  # the directory where write.table will write
setwd("c:/WorkDir/Alpha/")  # set the working directory
```

If you want absolute links, you can use file.path (see `?file.path`)

```
file.name = "myfile.sql"
abs_path = file.path("c:/WorkDir/Alpha/", file.name)
print(abs_path)  # [1] "c:/WorkDir/Alpha/myfile.sql"
```

Finally, I don't understand what you want to do with the `rbind`, it doesn't make sense to me. If you want to have the same name suffixed with new, try using the paste function.

Try to start from this, and use abusively the doc with `?setwd`, `?rbind`, etc.

```
# Control your working directory
# use setwd() to change your working directory
print(paste("Working in ", getwd(), " directory")) 

path = "c:/WorkDir/Alpha/"
file.names <- dir(path, pattern =".sql")
for(file.name in file.names){
    file <- read.table(file.name)
    result.replacement = gsub("Merry Christmas", "Happy New Year", file)
    write.table(result.replacement, 
                file=paste(file.name, "new.sql", sep="_"))
}
```

**UPDATE**

As your data is in plain text, you need to use `?readChar` and `?writeChar` to read/write your data.

```
library(tools)  # To get some information about paths
path = "c:/WorkDir/Alpha/"
file.names <- dir(path, pattern =".sql")
for(file.name in file.names){
    file.ext = file_ext(file.name)
    file.wthout_ext = file_path_sans_ext(file.name)

    file.content <- readChar(file.name, file.info(file.name)$size)
    result = gsub("Merry Christmas", 
                         "Happy New Year", 
                         file.content)

    writeChar(result, 
                con=paste(file.wthout_ext, "_new.", file.ext, sep=""))
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for help, I'm good up to the point of hitting problem with <read.table(file.name)>  it's just free text file and i'm getting bunch of msgs like :  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'C:/WorkDir/Alpha/xx1.SQL'  . I don't have any columns/structure/delimeters

Comment: For now I added end of line and loop is working, but when if not match in string then result.replacement shows some numeric indexes not actual content of file, is there any other option to handle this?

Comment: If the files you are reading are not structured, read.table is not the right function to use. try maybe a `file <-readChar(file.name, file.info(file.name)$size)`

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to do what you intend, but I'm afraid you won't be able to read .sql using the `read.table` function. Also, ideally, your `write.table` should be placed out of the loop. If you want to keep it inside, you want to add `append = TRUE`.

```
path = "C:/WorkDir/Alpha/"
out.file<-""
file.names <- dir(path, pattern =".sql")
for(i in 1:length(file.names)){
gsub( "Merry Christmas", "Happy New Year", file )
  file <- read.table(file.names[i])
  out.file <- rbind(out.file, file)
}
 write.table(out.file, file = "yourBigFile.txt", row.names = FALSE, qmethod = "double")
```

Comment: Thanks, all. I finished doing this in Ruby which was very easy, I'll keep and learn R for stat purposes.